# docker-compose - networks - /etc/hosts is not updated

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using `Docker version 1.12.3` and `docker-compose version 1.8.1`. I have some services which contains for example elasticsearch, rabbitmq and a webapp

My problem is that a service can not access another service by its host becuase docker-compose does not put all service hots in `/etc/hosts` file. I don't know their IP's because it is defined on `docker-compose up` phase.

I use `networks` feature as it is described at https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ instead of `links` because I do circular reference and `links` doesn't support it. But using `networks` does not put all services hosts to each service nodes `/etc/hosts` file. I set container_name, I set hostname but nothing happened. What I am missing;

Here is my docker-compose.yml;

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: elasticsearch:5.0
    container_name: "elasticsearch1"
    hostname: "elasticsearch1"
    command: "elasticsearch -E cluster.name=GameOfThrones -E node.name='Ned Stark' -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3"
    volumes:
      - "/opt/elasticsearch/data"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - webapp

  elasticsearch2:
    image: elasticsearch:5.0
    container_name: "elasticsearch2"
    hostname: "elasticsearch2"
    command: "elasticsearch -E cluster.name=GameOfThrones -E node.name='Daenerys Targaryen' -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3"
    volumes:
      - "/opt/elasticsearch/data"
    networks:
      - webapp

  elasticsearch3:
    image: elasticsearch:5.0
    container_name: "elasticsearch3"
    hostname: "elasticsearch3"
    command: "elasticsearch -E cluster.name=GameOfThrones -E node.name='John Snow' -E discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=elasticsearch1,elasticsearch2,elasticsearch3"
    volumes:
      - "/opt/elasticsearch/data"
    networks:
      - webapp


  rabbit1:
    image: harbur/rabbitmq-cluster
    container_name: "rabbit1"
    hostname: "rabbit1"
    environment:
      - ERLANG_COOKIE=abcdefg
    networks:
      - webapp

  rabbit2:
    image: harbur/rabbitmq-cluster
    container_name: "rabbit2"
    hostname: "rabbit2"
    environment:
      - ERLANG_COOKIE=abcdefg
      - CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1
      - ENABLE_RAM=true
    networks:
      - webapp

  rabbit3:
    image: harbur/rabbitmq-cluster
    container_name: "rabbit3"
    hostname: "rabbit3"
    environment:
      - ERLANG_COOKIE=abcdefg
      - CLUSTER_WITH=rabbit1
    networks:
      - webapp




  my_webapp:
    image: my_webapp:0.2.0
    container_name: "my_webapp"
    hostname: "my_webapp"
    command: "supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf -n"
    environment:
       - DYNACONF_SETTINGS=settings.prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    tty: true
    networks:
      - webapp


networks:
  webapp:
    driver: bridge
```

This is how I understand they can't comunicate with each other;

I get this error on elasticserach cluster initialization;

`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch3`

And this is how I docker-composing

`docker-compose up`

Comment: Looks fine to me. Docker doesn't use `/etc/hosts` anymore, everything is done via internal DNS. Are you saying your services can't communicate with each other? How are you trying to call them? Should just be able to use the service name.

Comment: @johnharris85, I updated the question. I see `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: elasticsearch3` on elasticsearch cluster initialization and I just use `docker-compose up` on my local Mac OS computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the container expects the hostname to be available immediate when the container starts that is likely why it's failing.

The hostname isn't going to exist until the other containers start. You can use an entrypoint script to wait until all the hostnames are available, then `exec elasticsearch ...`